# How do I set VERBOSITY in ROS for individual nodes?

Tags: ros

I would like a specific node in my ROS package to display output at the DEBUG verbosity level, while other nodes to display at the INFO level. I am aware of the rosconsole [configuration file](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration), and am able to set verbosity for a package with:

```
log4j.logger.ros.my_package=DEBUG
```

However, the following does not work:

```
log4j.logger.ros.my_package.my_node=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is running rqt_logger_level GUI.
If you have no GUI on robot, you can do that using service :

```
rosservice call /my_node/set_logger_level "{logger: 'rosout', level: 'debug'}"
```

Replace `my_node` and `debug` to specify the node and verbosity level, respectively.

Comment: The specific command that worked for me:
rosservice call /[name]/set_logger_level "{logger: 'rosout', level: 'info'}"

Comment: A drawback is that you have to rerun it everytime you restart your node, which can be very inconvenient (or even infeasible if it is about output during initialisation).