# Why is ROSBag record only recording ten events per second from any sensor?

Tags: ros, rosbag

The example ROSBags provided as part of Cartographer's tutorials (https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demos.html) have a message frequency of about 1507 messages per second for LiDAR messages, and 250 messages per second from an IMU.  I have an IMU broadcasting about 100 messages per second, and a Velodyne VLP-16 broadcasting messages using Velodyne's own driver (VLP16_points.launch).  For both sensors, rosbag record only seems to record up to 10 messages per second.  How can I increase this recording frequency?

Comment: How are you calling rosbag? Via launch file, or with your own node?

Comment: Just from the command line: rosbag record imu points2

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that rather being a function of a time limiter (ex, a frequency passed to a timer callback that does recording, like you might be expecting), it's actually a buffer bottleneck.

It's only taking in so much data to write to disk, or data in the subscriber buffers, before it's dropping frames to write or process the data already there.

Aside from writing your own node using their C++ api and profiling the issue itself (also a valid & not too difficult option, if very necessary), there are some commandline built-in parameters that control the buffer sizes (below, emphasis added).

I also recommend calculating what your desired recording rate is in kB/s; if you know the size of one lidar msg, by how many you want to store, and the rate they're generated (`rostopic hz`/`rostopic bw`), to give you a good estimation for what you're actually asking.

> `-b SIZE, --buffsize=SIZE`
>
> Use an internal buffer of SIZE MB (Default: 256, 0 = infinite). This
> is the message queue of the recorder object, before messages are being
> passed on to the bag. **Lowering this value might result in messages
> being dropped** before they reach the recording process.
>
> `$ rosbag record -b 1024 /chatter`
>
> `--chunksize=SIZE`
>
> Advanced. Record to chunks of SIZE KB (Default: 768). This is a buffer
> within the bag file object. Lowering this value will result in more
> writes to disk.
>
> `$ rosbag record --chunksize=1024 /chatter`

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record

---

Edits from Comments:

The two options above affect the buffers of serialized messages, when the raw topic msg is converted to text and stored. If they're being exceeded, [there should be ROS_WARN msgs](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/c7c5bcb22780e7f6dbbff9bc923afca34fd612b6/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp#L364) in your terminal. ([If not, you can enable them.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39722091/))

If you do not see any ROS_WARN msgs about dropped frames, then the issue may be normal dropped ros msgs. [Refering to previous questions](https://answers.ros.org/question/244311/how-to-detect-subscriber-drops-a-message/), you can [enable topic statistics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics) to see if any msgs are being dropped because of queue size.
From the source code, for the commandline tool, each subscribed topic only has a msg buffer of 100 ([ops.queue_size = 100;](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/c7c5bcb22780e7f6dbbff9bc923afca34fd612b6/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp#L263)). If this is the problem, the easiest solution is to copy the source package from github to your workspace, and modify the queue size. But I suspect that's not the real issue.

If you're recording more than 10 topics, there hypothetically could be another issue, as by default it ["only" launches 10 'async spinner' threads](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/c7c5bcb22780e7f6dbbff9bc923afca34fd612b6/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp#L244); but all the other mentioned potential issues are more likely to be the root causes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it seems regardless of which values I pass to --chunksize or -b in the command line call of rosbag record, both the imu and Velodyne_Points data are only recorded ten times per second.

Comment: I added a few more details; there is no limitation within the source code for frequency, only memory size (queue/buffer) limitations. I would double check there's no warning printouts, look at the recorded data for dropped msgs by the seq number, and try to narrow down your problem with these diagnostic tools. If you find a deeper problem, that is likely then another, different good question then what you asked. Though this answer doesn't really tell you _why_ in your particular case, but the answer should be within this scope of debugging.